# Convert or modify ansible-playbook output to json or python readable dictionary?

Tags: json, python-3.x, ansible

The ansible-playbook output is bit unparsable to use in some code (python or javascript),

how to turn the ansible output to some well structured json or python dictionary output.

the current output looks like this

```
PLAY [Cisco Switch Configuration] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [show uptime and show interface] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.135.147.138]
ok: [10.135.147.205]
ok: [10.135.147.134]

TASK [Display raw output] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.135.147.205] => {
    "show_output.stdout": [
        "sr12sw0013 uptime is 2 weeks, 5 days, 3 hours, 1 minute"
    ]
}
ok: [10.135.147.134] => {
    "show_output.stdout": [
        "sr12swp004 uptime is 2 weeks, 5 days, 3 hours, 1 minute\nSwitch uptime                      : 2 weeks, 5 days, 3 hours, 3 minutes"
    ]
}
ok: [10.135.147.138] => {
    "show_output.stdout": [
        "sr12swp008 uptime is 2 weeks, 5 days, 3 hours, 1 minute"
    ]
}
```

but I want it in something like json key pair value like

```
{
   "10.135.147.138": "sr12sw0013 uptime is 2 weeks, 5 days, 3 hours, 1 minute",
   "10.135.147.138": "sr12sw0013 uptime is 2 weeks, 5 days, 3 hours, 1 minute",
}
```

my current playbook looks like this

```
---
- name: Cisco Switch Configuration
  hosts: eleni
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  vars:
    ansible_network_os: ios
    ansible_connection: network_cli

  tasks:
    - name: show uptime and show interface
      ios_command:
        commands:
          # - show interface
          - show version | i uptime
      register: show_output

    - name: Display raw output 
      debug:
        var: show_output.stdout
```

Comment: Did you see this: [How can I parse metadata from show version (cisco ios) using ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69721341/how-can-i-parse-metadata-from-show-version-cisco-ios-using-ansible)

Comment: In such case it is recommend to [Parse semi-structured text with Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/cli_parsing.html) via `cli_parse` or to use [`ios_facts` module – Module to collect facts from remote devices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/ios/ios_facts_module.html).

Comment: Would this help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70902444/ansible-job-output-to-json-file-while-keeping-default-stdout ?

Answer (score 1):

The playbook output is by default designed to be human-readable and is not intended to be parsed. On the other hand, variables/facts could be processed using filters and then easily dumped into YAML- or JSON-formatted files to be parsed by any external tools later:

```yaml
# your current data collection code goes here

- name: Create the output file
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Collect the data to a single fact
      set_fact:
        some_collected_stats: >-
          {{
            some_collected_stats
            | default({})
            | combine({ hostvars[item]. inventory_hostname: hostvars[item].show_output.stdout
          }}
      loop: "{{ groups.eleni }}"

    - name: Dump the collected data to a file
      copy:
        dest: uptime_stats.json
        content: "{{ some_collected_stats | to_nice_json }}"
```

This example makes use of [`combine`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/combine_filter.html) filter as well as `groups` and `hostvars` [magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) and gives the output exactly in the format you requested.

But applying the approaches shared by [Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman) and [U880D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6771046/u880d) in the comments section could totally eliminate the need to use the external tools, so I would highly recommend to follow their suggestions.